# Does "Sure fix for conflicts" need a hyphen between "Sure" and "fix"?

Tags: hyphenation

A friend is using the tagline Sure fix for conflicts.  He says sure fix needs a hyphen (Sure-fix).  I'm not sure. Which is correct and why?

Comment: I don't know what a "tagline" means in this context. But hyphenated or not, ***sure fix*** doesn't sound like a natural collocation to me. Perhaps your friend is erroneously extrapolating from the common noun phrase [***a sure-fire fix***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+sure+fire+fix%22), which ***is*** hyphenated.

Comment: It's a tagline for marketing his service. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

If "sure" is used as an adjective or adverb (the only options [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sure) presents), it is a clear case. It must stay a separate word, and doing otherwise would be wrong.

I cannot find the phrase "sure-fix" in any of my usual dictionaries.

My conclusion: **Your friend is misguided from the standard English point of view.**

Comment: For what it's worth, I have heard the expression *sure fix* before. No doubt it's just a shortened version of *sure-fire*, but people have used it.

Answer (score 0):

I’d agree with Fumble fingers. Especially agree in the context of being related to conflicts. They were probably thinking of the tagline “Sure-fire Fix” to indicate they dolve problems or resolve conflicts, or simiilar such. They just forgot the full colloquialism.